# Sending message to objectForKey to NSMutableArray instance, And it works!! Strange?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, selector

I have a very bad code written in my program, was just playing around as I am learning Objective C and iOS platform. What I did is,

I have created `NSMutableArray` like this,

```
placeInfo = [NSMutableArray array];
```

and than later in my code I am doing something like this, basically I am manipulating Google places api response(JSON).

```
NSDictionary *results = [responseString JSONValue];
placeInfo = [results objectForKey:@"result"];
self.phoneNumber = (NSString *)[placeInfo objectForKey:@"formatted_phone_number"]; // In this line compiler warns me that NSMutableArray might not response to this.
```

I checked documentation but I didn't find objectForKey in `NSMutableArray`.

- **So what could be the reason? Why my code isn't crashing? Why it is returning phone number by "formatted_phone_number" key?**

**EDIT**

After first answer I have edited my code and added type casting like this, but it still works.

```
NSDictionary *results = [responseString JSONValue];
placeInfo = (NSMutableArray *)[results objectForKey:@"result"];
self.phoneNumber = (NSString *)[placeInfo objectForKey:@"formatted_phone_number"];
```

Comment: placeInfo is whatever [results objectForKey:@"result"] returns, which is probably not an NSArray. Did you inspect it in the debugger?

Comment: @VladimirGritsenko, Yeah that helped a lot to understand, thanks :)

Comment: The key here is the way that Objective-C works. It will send whatever message you tell it to to the object, regardless of the type you may think it is, or the type you cast it to. If you add a line like `NSLog(@"%@", placeInfo);` to your code, you'll see what type of object it actually is at runtime (as other people have suggested, most likely another NSDictionary).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’ve never used the Google Places API, but I’d guess `[results objectForKey:@"result"]` actually returns another dictionary, so the `objectForKey:` works.

Because objective-c just uses pointers to refer to objects, it’s never actually being converted to an `NSMutableArray`. Also, objective-c doesn't know at compile time if a method will exist, due to its dynamic nature (you can actually add methods and even whole classes at runtime).

Depending on the compiler settings, it may just show a warning that `objectForKey:` *might* not be found at runtime, and let it continue compiling anyway. It ends up working just fine if you actually passed it an `NSDictionary`.

Even when you put the `(NSMutableArray *)` cast in front of it, it won’t change anything. That simply casts the pointer type, and doesn’t actually change the object in any way.

Comment: Added note about casting. That simply casts the pointer, and doesn't change how the object responds to messages.

Comment: If you change all your types to just `id`, you’ll find it probably still works just fine – the type of the pointer doesn't change anything about the objects themselves.

Comment: @all , Yes you were right...I have to grok this thoroughly now :)

Answer (score 2):

It's doing this because `[results objectForKey:@"result"]` is returning you something that is not an `NSMutableArray`. That something that's being returned is likely another `NSDictionary` which, of course, does respond to `objectForKey:` To find out what you've got, set a breakpoint after `result = [placeInfo objectForKey:@"result"]` and inspect `result`. The debugger will tell you what kind of object you're dealing with. I'll bet you anything you like that it's an `NSDictionary`.

Objective C allows you to send any message (called a selector) to any object at any time; the runtime does not care whether a particular object implements a given selector. If the target object does not respond to a given selector it will ignore it. It will not crash. In this respect it's utterly unlike most other OOP languages, including C++ and Java, which will fail to compile if you try to call a method that a particular class doesn't implement. You can find out if an object responds to a given selector (which is analagous to using introspection to see if a given class implements a certain method) by saying `[result respondsToSelector:@selector(objectForKey:)]`. This difference between methods and messages is critically important to understanding Objective C. I'd recommend reading [The Objective C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html) before doing anything else.

Also, Objective C's type system is less stringently enforced than those other languages. It's quite legal (although a very bad idea) to do what you have done here, which is to declare a pointer of type `NSMutableArray` and then assign it to (I'm guessing) an `NSDictionary`.